# How to setup Lirc in 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, lirc

I upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 and there `irw` does not output a thing.

I did what is told in [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lirc/+bug/1791409/comments/2), but I guess I should reconfigure Lirc somehow.

Here is some terminal output:

```
 $ systemctl status lircd.service 
● lircd.service - Flexible IR remote input/output application support
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lircd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-02-27 18:16:26 EET; 19h ago
     Docs: man:lircd(8)
           http://lirc.org/html/configure.html
 Main PID: 958 (lircd)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4307)
   CGroup: /system.slice/lircd.service
           └─958 /usr/sbin/lircd --nodaemon

 helmi 28 14:06:52 jarnos-MacBook lircd[958]: lircd-0.10.0[958]: Error: Cannot glob /sys/class/rc/rc0/input[0-9]*/event[0-9]*
helmi 28 14:06:52 jarnos-MacBook lircd-0.10.0[958]: Error: Cannot glob /sys/class/rc/rc0/input[0-9]*/event[0-9]*
helmi 28 14:06:53 jarnos-MacBook lircd[958]: lircd-0.10.0[958]: Error: Cannot glob /sys/class/rc/rc0/input[0-9]*/event[0-9]*
helmi 28 14:06:53 jarnos-MacBook lircd-0.10.0[958]: Error: Cannot glob /sys/class/rc/rc0/input[0-9]*/event[0-9]*
helmi 28 14:06:54 jarnos-MacBook lircd[958]: lircd-0.10.0[958]: Error: Cannot glob /sys/class/rc/rc0/input[0-9]*/event[0-9]*
helmi 28 14:06:54 jarnos-MacBook lircd-0.10.0[958]: Error: Cannot glob /sys/class/rc/rc0/input[0-9]*/event[0-9]*
helmi 28 14:06:55 jarnos-MacBook lircd[958]: lircd-0.10.0[958]: Error: Cannot glob /sys/class/rc/rc0/input[0-9]*/event[0-9]*
helmi 28 14:06:55 jarnos-MacBook lircd-0.10.0[958]: Error: Cannot glob /sys/class/rc/rc0/input[0-9]*/event[0-9]*
helmi 28 14:06:56 jarnos-MacBook lircd[958]: lircd-0.10.0[958]: Error: Cannot glob /sys/class/rc/rc0/input[0-9]*/event[0-9]*
helmi 28 14:06:56 jarnos-MacBook lircd-0.10.0[958]: Error: Cannot glob /sys/class/rc/rc0/input[0-9]*/event[0-9]*
```

Comment: What did launchpad tell you to do? Are you sure Lirc is still installed? When you upgrade distros it will remove some software during the upgrade as not all repos are turned on by default.

Comment: @Rumbles it is explained in the web page. Lirc is installed, but there seems to be some problem. I will add some information in the description.

Comment: The configuration file /usr/share/lirc/remotes/vlsystem/lircd.conf.mplay
for my remote does not exists anymore.

Comment: ACCESS THESE LINKS BELOW, MAY HELP YOU SOLVE YOUR PROBLEM IF IT HAS NOT BEEN SOLVED. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=932779
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57437261/setup-ir-remote-control-using-lirc-for-the-raspberry-pi-rpi